# UWP C# Pivot Data Binding

Tags: c#, uwp, pivot

I'm trying to get a dynamic pivot. So dynamic headers and items. They depend on the number of Objects in a collection and they have a Name and a Title. 
But I don't know how to realize that, because I can't acces this data:

```
  <Pivot 
        x:Name="PivotExample"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Books}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="Books">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Books.Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Books.Title}"
             </DataTemplate>
  </Pivot>
```

I don't know how I can make it work. Help is appreciated.

Thanks
J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working sample (if you get any error messages during compilation, rebuild the project manually):

*MainPage.xaml*

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{x:Bind books}">

    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Book">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Book">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>

</Pivot>
```

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Book> books = new ObservableCollection<Book>
    {
        new Book { Name = "Name1", Title = "Title1" },
        new Book { Name = "Name2", Title = "Title2" },
        new Book { Name = "Name3", Title = "Title3" },
        new Book { Name = "Name4", Title = "Title4" }
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

*Book.cs*

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `x:Bind` uses `OneTime` `Mode` by default, which means changes made to the names and titles of the books won't be automatically reflected in the `Pivot` control. If that's not the desired behavior, then you'll need to use `OneWay` binding `Mode` and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the `Book` class:

*MainPage.xaml*

```
...
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
...
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=OneWay}"/>
...
```

*Book.cs*

```
public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You can use `nameof` operator to avoid magic strings in the setters.

Read more about data binding using `x:Bind` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).

Comment: That works perfectly fine. What if I want to show a Grid in the ItemTemplate instead?I created a grid in the same MainPage.xaml.cs but I work with the Grid in MainPage.cs. This Grid contains different Information about a Book

Comment: Just replace the `TextBlock` inside `DataTemplate` with your `Grid` and utilize data binding in the same manner as you did with `TextBlock` only now with the controls inside your `Grid`. [This video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-040-Data-Binding-to-the-GridView-and-ListView-Controls) may be of help.

Comment: The problem here is that when I have my Grid inside my DataTemplate which has a name> x:Name=BookGrid, I get the error that BookGrid in my xaml.cs is not found. So since the Grid is in my DataTemplate (in the .xaml data) the .xaml.cs data can't find it.

Comment: @J.Carden I see. Could you create a separate question and share your code there (both .xaml & .xaml.cs file)?